# Scraping data stored in a table of a website

Tags: r, html-table, rvest

I am trying to **scrape** a table from a website, using rvest package of R.

The website is: https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/es/san-bartolom%C3%A9/GCRR/date/2017-11-1

I found the selector of the table through google chrome (inspect)

```
#history-observation-table > tbody
```

I am running the following code:

```
url <- "https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/es/san-bartolom%C3%A9/GCRR/date/2017-11-1"

webpage <- read_html(url)

node <- html_nodes(webpage, '#history-observation-table > tbody')

data <- html_text(node)
```

I am receiving 0 though when trying to see what node has.

I think that the data of the table are not in a simple HTML format. Javascript is might being used? Moreover, I noticed that the table page is loaded after 2 or 3 seconds. At first a message appears that there are no data available, and after a while the table appears.

Comment: I suggest looking at the "rnoaa" package and downloading the data directly from the source as opposed to the weather channel/weather underground.  If you read the terms of service, the goverment's data is a better source.

Comment: The `XML` package has a function `readHTMLTable()`.